# Moving to meteor framework

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, meteor

I've started building a site using bootstrap, php, mysql and backbone.  I'm thinking of using the meteor framework instead.  I think I'll get more done in the same space of time with meteor.

The main part of my site will be image manipulation.  Specifically what I need to be able to do is to select an area on an image, typically a square or rectangle.  Store the coords of the selected portion of the image in a db and save the selected area as a new image.  I would need to create CSS dynamically, currently a php script is doing that job.

There could potentially be a lot of database records and I'm not familiar with Mongo so not sure if that would slow it down.

I can see on atmospherejs.com that there are imagemagick packages but I'm not sure will achieve this.

Anyone have any idea if meteor would be able to do what I want?

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions :)

Comment: Yes, but that code is not meteor or backbone specific. They are just frameworks and you could achieve this in either. Mongodb could work fine for this sort of thing. If the image is not on the server you need to decide whether to do the image manipulation work on the front or backend - both would look similar using JavaScript. On the backend you also have easy access to anything you can find that will help on npmjs.org (Meteor has the concept of a /server/ folder for node.js based server-side code)

Comment: Thank you, the image manipulation would need to be done on the backend so I'll see what I can find on npmjs.org.  Also I heard, meteor is synchronous since it uses Fibre which means you lose a massive benefit of using Node in the first place.  Is there any truth to that?

Comment: Np. Not at all Fibers is a different way of writing callbacks/promises which is similar to the up and coming "function generators" which is in node 0.11 and will be in ECMAScript 6. It's just another, some might say cleaner, way to do async code so shouldn't effect performance

Comment: Thank you again for that.  I guess if I can find a node package then this should be doable.  I'm currently using Jcrop for the front end part of it, so I don't see any reason to stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the image manipulation can be achieved on the backend.

This is the main function that looks like what I'm after.

http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#region